# Auto fill the new file with default content - vi

Tags: linux, bash, vim

I want to auto fill the new file that i open using VI with the default content.

I have tried it in Unix way, by creating bash function.

```
mkcpp()
{
    cp /home/$USER/.default.cpp $1
    vi $1
}
```

where .default.cpp will have default content.

```
 #include <iostream>
 using namespace std;
 int main()
 {

     return 0;
 }
```

if I want to create a new cpp file now I say 'mkcpp test.cpp' that will create required file. I want to get rid of 'mkcpp'. Is there any generic way of doing it using vi/vim scripts ? so that I can use vi itself to populate file based on the file extension like .c, .cpp, .sh

Comment: Have a look at the linked question. If you use `au BufNewFile *.c` you can read in your template file in place of the `skeleton.R` file the question references.

Comment: I have tried adding it to vimrc as suggested in that post. But i am getting the below error  

    **Error detected while processing BufNewFile Auto commands for "*.cpp":
    E20: Mark not set**

can you please help.

Comment: Please post the exact command you added to your vimrc

Comment: Try to remove the quotes (`'`) from your autocmd.

Comment: @Michael here is the command.
`augroup templates
  au!
    autocmd BufNewFile *.cpp '0r ~/.vim/templates/skeleton.cpp'
 augroup END`